# Thread safety for OrganizationServiceProxy and generated xrm service context

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

This is a best practices question.
 Per this [best practices article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509027.aspx#Performance) and per MSDN, the [`OrganizationServiceProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationserviceproxy.aspx) is not thread safe.

If you have a multi threaded client application in which you are creating an instance of an
 [`OrganizationServiceContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationservicecontext.aspx) (on a per thread basis), the constructor of which accepts an
 [`IOrganizationService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.aspx) instance and you pass in a global instance of the [`OrganizationServiceProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationserviceproxy.aspx) 
(i.e a static instance allocated once at the "process level"), will this cause threading issues and/or if the [`OrganizationServiceProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationserviceproxy.aspx)  instance faults, will it affect operations that the threads try to perform on their own "local" instance of the [`OrganizationServiceContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationservicecontext.aspx)?

My belief is that it will, and that an [`OrganizationServiceProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationserviceproxy.aspx) instance needs to be created on a "per thread" basis and that each [`OrganizationServiceContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationservicecontext.aspx) in a multi threaded application would need its **own corresponding** [`OrganizationServiceProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationserviceproxy.aspx) instance.

I'm posting this to get confirmation of the above.

Also, the article indicates

> The service proxy class performs the metadata download and user authentication by using the following class methods

```cs
IServiceManagement<IOrganizationService> orgServiceManagement =
                 ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IOrganizationService>(
                 new Uri(organizationUrl))

AuthenticationCredentials authCredentials = orgServiceManagement.Authenticate(credentials)
```

> *By caching the service management and authenticated credential objects, your application can more efficiently construct the service proxy objects more than one time per application session*

If I try to execute the above API calls manually, in Active directory authentication mode, the `authCredentials.SecurityTokenResponse` is null as [indicated by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg307068.aspx)

Is there a way to perform the authentication just once for AD mode and pass an **authenticated** [`SecurityTokenResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.authenticationcredentials.securitytokenresponse.aspx) to a newly created [`OrganizationServiceProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationserviceproxy.aspx) via the following constructor?

```cs
OrganizationServiceProxy (IServiceConfiguration, SecurityTokenResponse)
```

so that you don't have to take the authentication and metadata download hit on a "per thread basis" when constructing the [`OrganizationServiceProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationserviceproxy.aspx) instance per thread and just take the hit once?

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2012/09/07/optimize-crm-2011-service-channel-allocation-for-multi-threaded-processes-using-net-task-parallel-library-tpl-and-a-thread-local-service-proxy.aspx) is worth a read regarding cached proxy objects and the .NET Task Parallel library.

Comment: As far as getting a SecurityTokenResponse using AD credentials, the only way is to use ADFS, which provides the required tokenizing layer over the AD authentication service.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will definitely have issue if you attempt multi-threaded operations on a single IOrganization service.

We have two basic multi-threaded CRM applications: batch processors, and another web app.  For the batch programs I've found it works better to only have 10 different threads, and to batch up the work among the 10 different threads.  So if you're inserting 100,000 records, split them into 10 batches of 10,000, a single organization service for each thread.

We also have a website that does a lot of CRM interactions so there is no real way to batch the requests, so we created a CRM connection pool to reuse any open, already authenticated connections.

Of course this won't work at all if you're not using some system service account.

Comment: Daryl: Can you elaborate on your connection pooling? I would think that you would run into threading issues here as well if you pool OrganizationServiceProxy objects and if more than one web request thread ends up sharing the same OrganizationServiceProxy object with another thread processing a different web request.

Comment: I created a connection pool class that implements I disposable and has basically one public method, GetConnection.  You pass in the information you need for the connection, and the pool creates a connection the first time through (it'll create up to 10 I think),  When that thread is done, it'll exit the using statement, and the connection pool class will just mark the connection as free.  The next time a thread needs that same exact type of connection, it will give it one from the free pool.

Comment: @Daryl Can you please add Connection pool class code here ?

Comment: @Dot_NET Pro toothache code has been lost to the annals of history

Comment: @Daryl I know this is very old, but do you have any similar code class or link you can share that would be great thanks

Comment: Sorry @Dot_Net Pro .  I don't have anything to share with you.  I basically wrote my own IOrganizationService implementation that mapped all calls to the real service, and then in the IDispose, it released the service to the thread pool.